# How to center a navigation menu -- both left edge of menu item and right edge must be center?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, center, centering

I want to make a dropdown menu with 9 menu items. It should be in 2 rows (5+4 items) and it's items should be centered, but when making it center I put 20% width for `li` for get 5 items in one row. When making it center did `text-align : center` for `li` but it doesn't work because list item names are different, so the top item's edge and bottom item's edge doesn't come to the same line. See the picture attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tL8H.jpg)

```
          <li class="menu">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                <div class="dropmenu">
                        <div class="inner-dropmenu">
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav"></span> Link1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav1"></span> Link222</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav2"></span> Link33</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav3"></span> Link4444</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav4"></span> Link_a </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav5"></span> Link9</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav6"></span> Link_bb </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav7"></span> Link_ccc</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav nav8"></span>Link_dd</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: So where is your CSS? It's easier to give us your code instead of explaining your CSS through plain English.

Comment: Have you tried `margin:0 auto;` for the `ul`

Comment: please see the attached image...that's what exactly I  want.Not simple as putting margin:0 auto;